# C# (winforms) - Updating a DataGridView and a DataSet dynamically

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, winforms

I am trying to access a DataGridView through controls.find to update a database and then refresh it (it's data source is a DataSet).

Here is the code I currently have:

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();

commandInsert = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO logbook.item
                                (id_type,id_parent,column0001,column0002,column0003,column0004,column0005,column0006,column0007,column0008,column0009,column0010,column0011,column0012,
                                column0013,column0014,column0015,column0016,column0017,column0018,column0019,column0020,column0021,column0022,column0023,column0024,column0025,
                                column0026,column0027,column0028,column0029,column0030,column0031,column0032,column0033,column0034,column0035,column0036,column0037,column0038,
                                column0039,column0040,column0041,column0042,column0043,column0044,column0045,column0046,column0047,column0048,column0049,column0050)
                                VALUES
                                (@id_type,@id_parent,@column0001,@column0002,@column0003,@column0004,@column0005,@column0006,@column0007,@column0008,@column0009,@column0010,
                                @column0011,@column0012,@column0013,@column0014,@column0015,@column0016,@column0017,@column0018,@column0019,@column0020,@column0021,@column0022,
                                @column0023,@column0024,@column0025,@column0026,@column0027,@column0028,@column0029,@column0030,@column0031,@column0032,@column0033,@column0034,
                                @column0035,@column0036,@column0037,@column0038,@column0039,@column0040,@column0041,@column0042,@column0043,@column0044,@column0045,@column0046,
                                @column0047,@column0048,@column0049,@column0050)", conn);

commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_type", 5);
commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_parent", 2);
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0001", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0001");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0002", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0002");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0003", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0003");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0004", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0004");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0005", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0005");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0006", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0006");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0007", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0007");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0008", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0008");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0009", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0009");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0010", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0010");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0011", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0011");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0012", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0012");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0013", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0013");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0014", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0014");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0015", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0015");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0016", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0016");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0017", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0017");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0018", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0018");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0019", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0019");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0020", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0020");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0021", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0021");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0022", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0022");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0023", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0023");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0024", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0024");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0025", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0025");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0026", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0026");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0027", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0027");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0028", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0028");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0029", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0029");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0030", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0030");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0031", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0031");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0032", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0032");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0033", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0033");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0034", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0034");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0035", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0035");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0036", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0036");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0037", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0037");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0038", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0038");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0039", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0039");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0040", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0040");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0041", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0041");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0042", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0042");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0043", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0043");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0044", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0044");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0045", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0045");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0046", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0046");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0047", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0047");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0048", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0048");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0049", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0049");
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0050", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0050");

commandUpdate = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE logbook.item
                                SET
                                id_item = @id_item,id_type = @id_type,id_parent = @id_parent,column0001 = @column0001,column0002 = @column0002,column0003 = @column0003,
                                column0004 = @column0004,column0005 = @column0005,column0006 = @column0006,column0007 = @column0007,column0008 = @column0008,column0009 = @column0009,
                                column0010 = @column0010,column0011 = @column0011,column0012 = @column0012,column0013 = @column0013,column0014 = @column0014,column0015 = @column0015,
                                column0016 = @column0016,column0017 = @column0017,column0018 = @column0018,column0019 = @column0019,column0020 = @column0020,column0021 = @column0021,
                                column0022 = @column0022,column0023 = @column0023,column0024 = @column0024,column0025 = @column0025,column0026 = @column0026,column0027 = @column0027,
                                column0028 = @column0028,column0029 = @column0029,column0030 = @column0030,column0031 = @column0031,column0032 = @column0032,column0033 = @column0033,
                                column0034 = @column0034,column0035 = @column0035,column0036 = @column0036,column0037 = @column0037,column0038 = @column0038,column0039 = @column0039,
                                column0040 = @column0040,column0041 = @column0041,column0042 = @column0042,column0043 = @column0043,column0044 = @column0044,column0045 = @column0045,
                                column0046 = @column0046,column0047 = @column0047,column0048 = @column0048,column0049 = @column0049,column0050 = @column0050
                                WHERE id_item = @id_item;", conn);

commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("id_item", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_item");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id_type", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_type");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id_parent", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_parent");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0001", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0001");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0002", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0002");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0003", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0003");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0004", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0004");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0005", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0005");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0006", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0006");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0007", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0007");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0008", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0008");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0009", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0009");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0010", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0010");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0011", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0011");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0012", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0012");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0013", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0013");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0014", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0014");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0015", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0015");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0016", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0016");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0017", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0017");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0018", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0018");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0019", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0019");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0020", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0020");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0021", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0021");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0022", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0022");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0023", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0023");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0024", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0024");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0025", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0025");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0026", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0026");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0027", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0027");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0028", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0028");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0029", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0029");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0030", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0030");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0031", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0031");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0032", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0032");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0033", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0033");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0034", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0034");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0035", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0035");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0036", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0036");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0037", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0037");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0038", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0038");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0039", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0039");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0040", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0040");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0041", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0041");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0042", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0042");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0043", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0043");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0044", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0044");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0045", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0045");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0046", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0046");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0047", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0047");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0048", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0048");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0049", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0049");
commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0050", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0050");

mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = commandInsert;
mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandUpdate;

DataSet dataSetSender = new DataSet();
DataView dataViewSender = new DataView();
DataTable dataTableSender = new DataTable();
DataGridView dataGridViewReferer = new DataGridView();

dataGridViewReferer = this.Controls.Find(dataGridViewSender, true).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;
dataViewSender = (DataView)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource;
dataTableSender = dataViewSender.ToTable();
dataSetSender.Tables.Add(dataTableSender);

mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dataSetSender);
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();

dataGridViewReferer.Update();
dataGridViewReferer.Refresh();
```

The insert is working, unfortunately, instead of inserting only one row, it inserts all the DataGridView rows everytime (the updates do the same behavior as well).

As some notes, the DataSet name is created on Form_Load with it's name being kept in the actual database.

The goal behind this is to be able to generate DataGridViews at runtime and assign them DataSets in the same way.

The DataGridView is created through a button click:

```
ID = generateID();

dataGridView = new DataGridView();
dataGridView.Name = "dataGridView_" + loadedLogbook_filtered + "_" + ID;
dataGridView.Text = dataGridView.Name;
dataGridView.Location = new Point(8, 32);
dataGridView.Size = new Size(504, 504);
dataGridView.Visible = true;
dataGridView.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip_main;

dataGridView.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
dataGridView.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);
dataGridView.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
dataGridView.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseClick);
dataGridView.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(control_CellValueChanged);

this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(dataGridView);
```

I cannot find the source of the problem and I would need a little help.

May anyone provide me with some help regarding this issue please?

Thank you for your time and help, it is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is how I create the DataSet:

```
DataGridView dataGridViewReferer = this.Controls.Find(dataGridViewSender, true).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;
bool form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_setbuttonDataSetSetClicked = false;

using (Form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set = new Form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set())
{
    form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set.ShowDialog(this);
    form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_setbuttonDataSetSetClicked = form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set.buttonDataSetSetClicked;
    dataSetToSet = form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_set.dataSetToSet;

    if (form_contextMenuStrip_main_dataSet_setbuttonDataSetSetClicked == true)
    {
        dataSetToSetRefererer = new DataSet();
        DataSet dataSetCaller = new DataSet();

        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                    *
                                    FROM 
                                    item 
                                    WHERE
                                    id_type = @param_0001 and friendly_name=@param_0002", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_0001", 4);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_0002", dataSetToSet);

        mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSetCaller);

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

        string dataSetToFill = dataSetCaller.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();

        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                    *
                                    FROM 
                                    item 
                                    WHERE
                                    id_parent = @param_0001", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_0001", dataSetCaller.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

        mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSetToSetRefererer);

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        dataGridViewReferer.DataSource = dataSetToSetRefererer.Tables[0].DefaultView;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem ? A datagridview has a datasource this can be your dataset or at elast one table of it, and after assigning you format the view (blending columns out reformat ...) and then dot net interacts with the database and then you update only the data adapter, at least that is what ia am doing.

Comment: The issue is that whenever I click on the DataGridView and I modify a cell, or even insert a new one, if there was 10 rows in the DataGridView, it will insert all 10 of them back in the database (even on a cell update).

Comment: As i said in the comment before, try to update only the data.apdater to the displayed table which is the datasource of datagriedview. see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-data-adapter.html

Comment: I tried that originally:             dataGridViewReferer = this.Controls.Find(dataGridViewSender, true).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;
            dataViewSender = (DataView)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource;
            dataTableSender = dataViewSender.Table;
            dataSetSender.Tables.Add(dataTableSender);

            mySqlDataAdapter.Update(dataSetSender);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose(); and this is what I get (error): DataTable already belongs to another DataSet

Comment: Please try this approach http://solibnis.blogspot.com/2013/02/connecting-mysql-table-to-datagridview.html and use at first inly one table, before adding a second table . Like i oftenb repeat here programming is like writibg a timeline of actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, the main culprit is that I was using CellValueChanged instead of RowValidated of the DataGridView.

Here is the code that works for me, using the link nbk provided (which was really helpful):

```
private void control_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dataGridViewReferer = this.Controls.Find(dataGridViewSender, true).FirstOrDefault() as DataGridView;

    DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource).GetChanges();

    if (changes != null)
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        command = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT * from item WHERE id_type=@param_0001 and id_parent=@param_0002", conn);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_0001", 5);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_0002", 2);

        commandInsert = new MySqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO logbook.item
                                        (id_type,id_parent,column0001,column0002,column0003,column0004,column0005,column0006,column0007,column0008,column0009,column0010,column0011,column0012,
                                        column0013,column0014,column0015,column0016,column0017,column0018,column0019,column0020,column0021,column0022,column0023,column0024,column0025,
                                        column0026,column0027,column0028,column0029,column0030,column0031,column0032,column0033,column0034,column0035,column0036,column0037,column0038,
                                        column0039,column0040,column0041,column0042,column0043,column0044,column0045,column0046,column0047,column0048,column0049,column0050)
                                        VALUES
                                        (@id_type,@id_parent,@column0001,@column0002,@column0003,@column0004,@column0005,@column0006,@column0007,@column0008,@column0009,@column0010,
                                        @column0011,@column0012,@column0013,@column0014,@column0015,@column0016,@column0017,@column0018,@column0019,@column0020,@column0021,@column0022,
                                        @column0023,@column0024,@column0025,@column0026,@column0027,@column0028,@column0029,@column0030,@column0031,@column0032,@column0033,@column0034,
                                        @column0035,@column0036,@column0037,@column0038,@column0039,@column0040,@column0041,@column0042,@column0043,@column0044,@column0045,@column0046,
                                        @column0047,@column0048,@column0049,@column0050)", conn);

        commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_type", 5);
        commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_parent", 2);
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0001", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0001");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0002", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0002");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0003", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0003");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0004", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0004");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0005", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0005");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0006", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0006");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0007", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0007");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0008", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0008");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0009", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0009");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0010", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0010");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0011", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0011");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0012", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0012");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0013", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0013");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0014", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0014");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0015", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0015");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0016", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0016");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0017", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0017");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0018", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0018");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0019", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0019");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0020", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0020");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0021", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0021");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0022", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0022");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0023", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0023");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0024", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0024");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0025", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0025");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0026", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0026");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0027", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0027");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0028", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0028");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0029", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0029");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0030", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0030");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0031", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0031");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0032", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0032");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0033", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0033");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0034", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0034");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0035", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0035");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0036", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0036");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0037", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0037");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0038", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0038");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0039", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0039");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0040", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0040");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0041", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0041");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0042", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0042");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0043", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0043");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0044", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0044");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0045", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0045");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0046", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0046");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0047", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0047");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0048", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0048");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0049", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0049");
        commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@column0050", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0050");

        commandUpdate = new MySqlCommand(@"UPDATE logbook.item
                                        SET
                                        id_item = @id_item,id_type = @id_type,id_parent = @id_parent,column0001 = @column0001,column0002 = @column0002,column0003 = @column0003,
                                        column0004 = @column0004,column0005 = @column0005,column0006 = @column0006,column0007 = @column0007,column0008 = @column0008,column0009 = @column0009,
                                        column0010 = @column0010,column0011 = @column0011,column0012 = @column0012,column0013 = @column0013,column0014 = @column0014,column0015 = @column0015,
                                        column0016 = @column0016,column0017 = @column0017,column0018 = @column0018,column0019 = @column0019,column0020 = @column0020,column0021 = @column0021,
                                        column0022 = @column0022,column0023 = @column0023,column0024 = @column0024,column0025 = @column0025,column0026 = @column0026,column0027 = @column0027,
                                        column0028 = @column0028,column0029 = @column0029,column0030 = @column0030,column0031 = @column0031,column0032 = @column0032,column0033 = @column0033,
                                        column0034 = @column0034,column0035 = @column0035,column0036 = @column0036,column0037 = @column0037,column0038 = @column0038,column0039 = @column0039,
                                        column0040 = @column0040,column0041 = @column0041,column0042 = @column0042,column0043 = @column0043,column0044 = @column0044,column0045 = @column0045,
                                        column0046 = @column0046,column0047 = @column0047,column0048 = @column0048,column0049 = @column0049,column0050 = @column0050
                                        WHERE id_item = @id_item;", conn);

        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("id_item", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_item");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id_type", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_type");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@id_parent", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "id_parent");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0001", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0001");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0002", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0002");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0003", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0003");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0004", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0004");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0005", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0005");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0006", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0006");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0007", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0007");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0008", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0008");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0009", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0009");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0010", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0010");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0011", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0011");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0012", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0012");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0013", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0013");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0014", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0014");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0015", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0015");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0016", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0016");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0017", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0017");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0018", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0018");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0019", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0019");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0020", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0020");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0021", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0021");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0022", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0022");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0023", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0023");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0024", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0024");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0025", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0025");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0026", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0026");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0027", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0027");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0028", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0028");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0029", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0029");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0030", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0030");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0031", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0031");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0032", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0032");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0033", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0033");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0034", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0034");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0035", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0035");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0036", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0036");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0037", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0037");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0038", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0038");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0039", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0039");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0040", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0040");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0041", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0041");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0042", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0042");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0043", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0043");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0044", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0044");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0045", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0045");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0046", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0046");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0047", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0047");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0048", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0048");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0049", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0049");
        commandUpdate.Parameters.Add("@column0050", MySqlDbType.LongText, 15, "column0050");

        mySqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = commandInsert;
        mySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandUpdate;
        mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        mySqlDataAdapter.Update(changes);

        ((DataTable)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
        ((DataTable)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource).GetChanges();

        DataView dataViewSender = new DataView();
        DataTable dataTableSender = new DataTable();

        ((DataTable)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource).Rows.Clear();

        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill((DataTable)dataGridViewReferer.DataSource);

        dataGridViewReferer.Update();
        dataGridViewReferer.Refresh();
    }
}
```